# Why won't this forEach work in this else if statement?

Tags: javascript

Noob here. So, I'm working through Colt Steele's Web Developer Bootcamp and I'm really stuck. I just can't get this piece of code to run and it's copied directly from Colt. the code runs until it hits the forEach within the if statement. It's supposed to (as you can probably tell) iterate over the array and console.log each item in the array in a list but it just doesn't work and I have no idea why. I'd be very grateful for some guidance. Here is the code and thank you in advance.

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  var todos = ["buy new turtle"];
  var input = prompt("what would you like to do?");

  while (input !== "quit") {
    if (input === "list") {
      todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        console.log(todo);
      });
    } else if (input === "new") {
      var newTodo = prompt("enter new todo");
      todos.push(newTodo);
    }
    
    input = prompt("what would you like to do?");
  }
  
  console.log("ok, you quit the app");
}, 500);
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. How specifically does it fail to work for you?

Comment: it works fine for me too. But only thing is, I tried in jsfiddle and the console log is visible only after typing 'quit'

Comment: Yeah, same for me, pasted it into jsbin. And it works. https://jsbin.com/fodeguraru/edit?js,console

Comment: It may also be relevant to mention which browser you're using, I believe IE and Edge may still not support `forEach`

Comment: @Thangadurai Yeah, if you're using `prompt`, you might as well use `alert` instead of `console.log`. (To be sure, in production you'd use neither.)

Comment: @DBS Edge does, but Internet Exploder (up to and including 11) does not.

Comment: So I am using chrome @DBS.

Comment: @Amadan The code worked fine until you enter 'list' into the prompt and it would just do nothing. It then proceeds to ask you again what you would like to do. I did what you suggested and swapped out console.log for alert and that worked! but why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because in browsers `prompt` and `alert` are synchronous (everything stops till they are done), but `console.log` is not (console will update when it has time to do so).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!